# Django SQL backend strange output with timestamp/epoch

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I don't understand what's going on and what to write to google to find solution:

Seems like Django PostgreSQL database engine doing something strange?

first - simple query:

```
>>> data = DatabaseHistory.objects.filter(DatabaseId=8)

>>> data[0].timestamp

>>> 1409221590.77832
```

2nd - I put 1st query result to new query bot result is null (!?)

```
>>> data = DatabaseHistory.objects.filter(timestamp=1409221590.77832)

>>> data[0].timestamp

>>> IndexError: list index out of range
```

3rd - change __exact to __contains:

```
>>> data = DatabaseHistory.objects.filter(timestamp__contains=1409221590)

>>> data[0].timestamp

>>> 1409221590.64894

>>> data[1].timestamp

>>> 1409221590.77832
```

4th - check "digit sensitivity" of __contains operator - seems works for 2digit after dot

```
>>> data = DatabaseHistory.objects.filter(timestamp__contains=1409221590.77)

>>> data[0].timestamp

>>> 1409221590.77832
```

for 3digit after dot  - not working:

```
>>> data = DatabaseHistory.objects.filter(timestamp__contains=1409221590.778)

>>> data[0].timestamp

>>> IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: For the 2nd, the result isn't null, it's the empty set `[]`. `print repr(data)` to see, or if you're on the python interactive console, just type `data`<enter> . Anyway - I think you need to show the underlying SQL and the actual raw value in the table. Try `SET extra_float_digits = 3; SELECT version(); SELECT * from databasehistory where "timestamp" BETWEEN 1409221590.7 AND 1409221590.8` or something like that. Also show the output of `SHOW integer_datetimes;`.

Comment: Of what type is `timestamp`?